# Google Action language to Dialogflow language mapping

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

How do I link my Google Action languages to my Dialogflow languages?

My Google Action is not passing certification because my French Google Action is calling my English Dialogflow.  I thought Dialogflow would be smart enough to read "locale": "fr-FR" from my request's json, and route the request to the French version of my Dialogflow, but apparently not because it's responding with the English version.

Is there some way to map each language in my Google Action with its counterpart in Dialogflow?

This is what I see using the simulator:

Request:

```
{
  "user": {
    "user_id": "blah",
    "access_token": "blahblah",
    "permissions": [],
    "locale": "fr-FR",
    "last_seen": {
      "seconds": 1519777910
    },
    "package_entitlements": []
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversation_id": "1519777935448",
    "type": 1
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "assistant.intent.action.MAIN",
      "raw_inputs": [
        {
          "input_type": 2,
          "query": "Parler avec Déclencher CMD",
          "annotation_sets": []
        }
      ],
      "arguments": []
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      }
    ]
  },
  "is_in_sandbox": true,
  "available_surfaces": [
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "response_metadata": {
    "status": {},
    "query_match_info": {
      "query_matched": true,
      "intent": "Default Welcome Intent"
    }
  },
  "conversation_token": "[]",
  "expect_user_response": true,
  "expected_inputs": [
    {
      "input_prompt": {
        "rich_initial_prompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simple_response": {
                "text_to_speech": "Say something like, run calculator on laptop."
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "no_match_prompts": [],
        "no_input_prompts": []
      },
      "possible_intents": [
        {
          "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using a server for the Reply?

Answer (score 0):

As you can notice your request JSON keys are camel cased which means you are using **Actions on Google conversation API V1** which doesn't support multi-languages. Make sure to migrate to **V2** by checking the box in the "Additional Settings" section of the Google Assistant integration modal in Dialogflow (Check below image)

[image]

*Note that some projects do not display the V2 checkbox option. If it is the case with your project reach out to support.*